# Loading multiple images from multiple folders in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to stackoverflow and also in python. I'm trying to read multiple images from multiple folders to process them in numpy.

I tried to do this: (Below Code)

```
import os 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot

path = "../Desktop/folder"

for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):

   for name in files:
      if name.endswith(".png"):
          print(name)
      else:
          print("Nothing Found")
```

The code is working fine, but the output is given in a string (obviously). I want to do the same kind of work, but I want to read the whole image to process it in numpy array, instead of only string.

I will be very thankful if someone can show me a way for this.

P.S. Sorry if something is unclear or question is not direct. I'm new here and learning about that.

Thanks.

Comment: "I want to read the whole image to process": What do you mean by this ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: Like converting image to numpy array to process it in different image processing ways. Right now, I can only read them as string not as images.

Comment: `os.walk()` or `glob.glob()` only gives you the filenames, you'll need to `open()` the filenames or load them via your image processing modules to actually read and process the content.  I'm not familiar with `numpy` and image processing so I can't comment further on that.

Comment: I have already read 1000 of Image data which was only in one folder. But right now I have 100's of folders and each having more than 1000 Images. The only query I have is, How can I read all the folders and load all the images at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there! Once you have found each image file by looking at the extension, you need to reconstruct the full path. And then load the image into a numpy array. Fortunately, matplotlib image read function returns a numpy array !

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpplot
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

images = []
path = "../path/to/img/folder/"

for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    current_directory_path = os.path.abspath(root)
    for f in files:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if ext == ".png":
            current_image_path = os.path.join(current_directory_path, f)
            current_image = mpimg.imread(current_image_path)
            images.append(current_image)

for img in images:
    print img.shape
```

Here you can see the code doing these sugestions and storing the numpy arrays in a list of images. Then display the numpy array shape for each of these images.