# Open/read multiple .tif images from multiple folders on different levels

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, the scheme is that I have a folder, inside which there are other folders with `.tif` images. For instance I have something like that:

```
folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/image_1.tif
folder_1/folder_2/image_2.tif
folder_1/image_3.tif
folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/image_4.tif
```

I need to read **all** the `.tif` images from **all** folders. I tried this suggestion: [Loading all images using imread from a given folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230592/loading-all-images-using-imread-from-a-given-folder) but it does not work for variable path folders, as my scheme. So, after searching I tried this suggestion: [Loading multiple images from multiple folders in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282808/loading-multiple-images-from-multiple-folders-in-python) but I get this error:

```
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file(....)
```

Any idea how to read all `.tif` images from all folders, which vary in "folder distance" from the initial folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glob` module helps with this.

```
from glob import glob
import os.path
parent_dir = "C:\\folder_1"  # Or wherever your parent folder is
all_tif_file_paths = glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, "**", "*.tif"), recursive=True)
```

The `"**"` there means 'any number (including zero) of intervening directories', and when you use it, you need to specify `recursive=True`.

Then you can loop over `all_tif_file_paths` and read each file in turn.